# how to do single instance of a intent of a android class

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I am working on a app that when the user clicks the Google play music button it opens Google play music, However if you close the app and reopen it, it launches Google play music not the app I'm working on you have to click the back button to get back to the my apps screen and that's not a good user experience! So how do I fix this here's my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class QuickLaunch extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quick_launch);
    }

     /** Called when the user clicks the  music button */
     public void music(View view) {
         Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER");
         startActivity(intent);
     }



/** Called when the user clicks the play button */
public void play(View view) {
    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.vending");
    startActivity(launchIntent);
    }



/** Called when the user clicks the web button */
public void web(View view) {
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://google.com/"));
      startActivity(browserIntent);
}

       /** Called when the user clicks the email button */
public void email(View view) {
     Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.email");
     startActivity(intent);

} 

/** Called when the user clicks the sms button */
public void chat(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.d4a.sms","de.ub0r.android.smsdroid.ConversationListActivity"));
 intent.putExtra("grace", "Hi");
 startActivity(intent);
}


/** Called when the user clicks the settings button */
public void settings(View view) {
     Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.settings");
     startActivity(intent);

}



/** Called when the user clicks the camera button */
public void cam(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}

/** Called when the user clicks the video camara button */
public void video_cam(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}
}
```

please look at the play music snippet in the code to know what code I am using to launch google play music.

Comment: This is the expected behavior. When resuming an app, it typically continues with the most recently opened Activity, in this case the activity from Google Play Music.

Comment: so is there a way to fix that??

Comment: thanks for the link I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Code-Apprentice for providing that link the fix was easy in the manifest you need to add this line to the android activity:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

I hope this may help someone that was in my shoes!